# How to get today's date in Ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby, date

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3, and when I execute `Date.today`, I get `NoMethodError: undefined method`today' for Date:Class`

I'm pretty confused about this since it does appear to be in the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-today). Though I know this is the documentation for 2.0, but I see answers ranging back to when it was implemented in 1.8.7. Was this removed in 1.9?

Comment: Include require 'date'

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Did you `require 'date'` ?

```
> require 'date'
 => true
> Date.today
 => #<Date: 2013-03-12 ((2456364j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: In ruby, many libraries just add functionalities to existing class. I guess 'date' is one of them